# How to prevent linux xrdp from spanning multiple monitors

Tags: windows, centos, rdp, xrdp

I installed xrdp on centos 7 server. Am trying to connect to it using rdp from a windows 2012 box with "Use all monitors .." option selected.

Once I get into  the centos box, I see that the display is spanning both monitors that are connected. As a result, if i maximize chrome in the centos instance, it spans both monitors instead of just filling one monitor.

Tried the same by replacing the windows 2012 box with a windows 2008 r2 box.

Any ideas??

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.